# Stylish custom font

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a style to change font to a custom one for a project. the code seems to work in the editing window but real sites doesn't seem to work. I think its falling back on a system default. How do I get around this? I'm using chrome if that matters.

```
@font-face {
            font-family: 'wantedfont';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            src: local('wantedfont'),url(http://hazel-is.me/times_new_ancient.ttf);
}

*{
cursor: url(http://puu.sh/hoJq2/46859bf607.gif), progress;
font-family: wantedfont !important;
}
```

Comment: Does the font have appropriate permissions flags to be used in this way?

Comment: it has 777 permissions

Comment: are you sure you are using the same fonts? The local font is possibly present when you are viewing it.

Comment: What do you mean by same fonts?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "bulletproof" syntax and add a ☺︎ as local font name to make sure it does not load a local font. more importantly add format declaration, full rule should be as such:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Graublau Web';
  src: url('GraublauWeb.eot');
  src: local('☺︎'),
    url("GraublauWeb.woff") format("woff"),
    url("GraublauWeb.otf") format("opentype"),
    url("GraublauWeb.svg#grablau") format("svg");
  }
```